# Regular Expression issue

Tags: c#, regex, double, decimal

I have an issue regarding the use of the following regular expression:

```
private Regex _regexDecimals = new Regex(@"[^.,0-9]");
```

when I use above the result is dat I can use

1
0,5
,5
1.0

but when I enter .5 it results in an error trying it to convert it to a double.

Now I've made the following regular expression:

```
private Regex _regexDecimals = new Regex(@"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?");
```

This matches for using the dots, but not for using the comma's. How can I match also using the comma's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `\.` with `[.,]`

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to cast it to a double you should use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      "\\d*[.,]?\\d+",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

?

The '\d' is the equivalent of [0-9]